# Excel,Pivot table, subtract instead of using "difference from"

Tags: excel, excel-2010, pivot-table, difference, calculated-field

I have a pivot table (in Excel 2010), looking like something like this (Countries in columns, sellers(included Factory) in rows and sum of totals in values  :

```
**Country**  **Factory ** **Seller A**  **Seller B**  **Seller C**
USA              30           31                          19
GB               12                                       10
Denmark          14           16            20
```

What I need is to find a price difference between factory and store prices. I have tried "difference from" calculation with **supplier name** as a **base field** and **Factory** as a **base item**, but that is not what I really want. I.e it gives **Seller A -Factory**, but I would like to have **Factory-Seller A**, so the negative value would mean that buying from seller would mean, that I lose money, if I go buy from the Seller A. Additionally, I would like to have blanks (not difference) in the cases where the seller does not sell the item (where there is a blank in the data).

I.e the output would be

```
**Country**  **Factory ** **Seller A**  **Seller B**  **Seller C**
USA              0           -1                          11
GB               0                                       2
Denmark          0           -2            -6
```

It seems so easy, but I could not figure out how to write it as my own calculated field (or item? -however I can't add an item, get an error).

Can it even be done? I would think so as the "difference from" seems essentially the same thing, but as I don't know how that looks as a field formula, I can't replicate it. Hope its not too messy question, but I have tried to figure it out whole day. Maybe I am simply bad at googling things.

Comment: In order to do this, you have to expand your original field of data to include a difference column. This may not seem straightforward because you're thinking about the difference from the TOTAL count of factories. But including an additional (several?) columns is the answer to how to do this. It's hard to explain further without seeing your original dataset.

Comment: If you have Excel 2013 or later, or Excel 2010 with the free PowerPivot addin you could do this using Measures, which are basically formulas you can write inside a PivotTable using an Excel-like language called DAX.

Comment: The problem is that the "original data" is collation of multiple tabs on multiple workbooks and for creating a pivot, the data is filtered on a tab name. Adding the extra column do the data is not necessarily very difficult, but I'm not sure it is worth the effort as by idea I could simply make the calculations next to the pivot. However, I am a bit stubborn, and can't let go of the idea it can be done easily in pivot (as the difference from does half of the work, just other way around and creating base fields would allow me to leave blanks were needed. but I just can't put 1 and 1 together).

Comment: Unfortunately, do not have the PowerPivot add-in. working on companies computer so probably not allowed to add anything by myself.